# Defining custom keys for object types through JQ when converting text file into JSON format

Tags: json, bash, jq

Trying to create the following JSON structure through bash. There will be a max of 4 environments that I want to be shown even if there are no content within them, and example output can be found below the structure.

Input Text File:

```
DEV,Middleware,Mqwerty,Mqwerty
DEV,Middleware,Mqwerty,Mqwerty
DEV,Middleware,Mqwerty,Mqwerty
DEV,System,Sqwerty,Sqwerty
DEV,Application,Aqwerty,Aqwerty,Aqwerty
UAT,Application,Aqwerty,Aqwerty,Aqwerty
DEV,Utility,Uqwerty,Uqwerty,Uqwerty
PROD,Middleware,Mqwerty,Mqwerty
DEV,Middleware,Mqwerty,Mqwerty
```

Desired JSON Structure:

```
    {
    "ENV": {
        "DEV": {
            "Middleware": [
                {
                    "name": "Mqwerty",
                    "release": "Mqwerty"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Mqwerty",
                    "release": "Mqwerty"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Mqwerty",
                    "release": "Mqwerty"
                }
            ],
            "System": [
                {
                    "name": "Sqwerty",
                    "tag": "Sqwerty"
                }
            ],
            "Application": [
                {
                    "domain": "Aqwerty",
                    "host": "Aqwerty",
                    "user": "Aqwerty"
                },
                {
                    "domain": "Aqwerty",
                    "host": "Aqwerty",
                    "user": "Aqwerty"
                }
            ],
            "Utility": [
                {
                    "domain": "Uqwerty",
                    "health": "Uqwerty",
                    "version": "Uqwerty"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SIT": {
            "Middleware": [],
            "System": [],
            "Application": [],
            "Utility": []
        },
        "UAT": {
            "Middleware": [
                {
                    "name": "Mqwerty",
                    "release": "Mqwerty"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Mqwerty",
                    "release": "Mqwerty"
                }
            ],
            "System": [],
            "Application": [],
            "Utility": []
        },
        "PROD": {
            "Middleware": [],
            "System": [],
            "Application": [],
            "Utility": []
        }
    }
}
```

Some key notes, even in environments that don't have information, the 'template' of middleware, system, application and utility (lets call these categories) is still there. The categories also have a predefined key:value structure that follows:

Application (keys): domain, host, user

Utility: domain, health, version

Middleware: name, release

System: name, tag

This is the code I've been able to get so far, however its unable to add a particular set of keys for each category (Application, Utility, Middleware and System) and also isn't able to add all the values as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/jq -Rnf
reduce inputs as $line
  ( .ENV
    ["DEV", "SIT", "UAT", "PROD"]
    ["Middleware", "System", "Application", "Utility"] = []

  ; ($line | split(",")) as $elements
  | .ENV [$elements[0]] [$elements[1]] +=
    [ $elements[2:]
    | with_entries(.key |= "value\(.+1)")
    ]
  )
```

I really do appreciate any help and thank you for taking you time reading this questions, apologies for being a long one. Also any good resources regarding jq would be appreciated.

Comment: Apologies, my mistake. That has been edited now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to build up a solution from easily understood pieces. In this case, jq would be invoked with `-nR`.

```
def initial:
  null
  | .["DEV", "SIT", "UAT", "PROD"]["Middleware", "System", "Application", "Utility"] = [];

def objectify($keys):
  . as $in
  | reduce range(0; $keys|length) as $i ({}; .[$keys[$i]] = ($in[$i]) );

def object:
  .[0] as $top
  | .[1:] 
  | if   $top == "Middleware"  then objectify(["name", "release"])
    elif $top == "System"      then objectify(["domain", "tag"])
    elif $top == "Application" then objectify(["domain", "host", "user"])
    elif $top == "Utility"     then objectify(["domain", "health", "version"])
    else objectify( map(tostring) )  # or raise an error, or ...
    end;

reduce (inputs | split(",")) as $line (initial;
  getpath($line[0:2]) as $v
  | setpath($line[0:2]; $v + [$line[1:] | object] ))
| {ENV: .}
```

Comment: Thank you @peak this looks a lot easier to understand. I'm just having a little trouble running this. I stored the above code in a script titled "jqscript.jq" with a header of #!/usr/bin/jq -Rnf . Then was executing the script through the following command ./jqscript.jq inputfile

However it's throwing me the error "jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 18:
initial:
jq: 1 compile error" 

Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: There was a spurious . before the # comment.

Comment: Hi @peak , testing this code with a manually created "Input Text" (as shown in the question) works. However, I've found that when I have my bash script produce the input text file, the jq script ends up adding an additional "\r" to the last attribute of each object. For instance, if an application object was digested, the  user attribute would have the value "Aqwerty\r". Do you have any recommendations on how I could avoid this?

Comment: Try replacing ’inputs` by: inputs|sub("\r";"")

Answer (score 0):

Here's a DRYer and more declarative version of my other solution on this page.  It also handles the anomalous case slightly differently.

```
< input.txt jq -nR '

  def categories:
      { "Middleware":  ["name", "release"],
        "System":      ["domain", "tag"],
        "Application": ["domain", "host", "user"],
        "Utility":    ["domain", "health", "version"] };

  def initial:
    null
    | .["DEV", "SIT", "UAT", "PROD"][ categories | keys[]] = [];

  def objectify($keys):
    . as $in
    | reduce range(0; $keys|length) as $i ({}; .[$keys[$i]] = ($in[$i]) );

  def object:
    categories[.[0]] as $keys
    | .[1:] 
    | objectify($keys // [range(0;length) | tostring]);

reduce (inputs | split(",")) as $line (initial;
  getpath($line[0:2]) as $v
  | setpath($line[0:2]; $v + [$line[1:] | object] ))
| {ENV: .}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @peak ! I was also wondering if you have any good resources or tips to get better at dealing with jq. I was having a really troublesome time looking at the official jq documentation to figure this all out. Any recommendations would be super appreciated.

Comment: The jq FAQ page (https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ) has numerous pointers, and may be helpful in other ways as well. Feel free to let me know what you think of https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq

Comment: Hi @peak , thank you so much for all the help. Your input is invaluable. Could I ask with the syntax of the above answer. Is there a way to replace input.txt with a variable that contains the contents of inputs.txt e.g. $(cat intput.txt) ?

Comment: Why not just: `echo "$x" | ....`?  Or consider: `x=abcd jq -n 'env.x'`